# How to change the Email FROM Name with NodeJs aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, aws-sdk, amazon-simple-email-service

I am sending Emails via the `aws-sdk` for Nodejs like this:

```
const params = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [... ],
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: `...`,
                Charset: 'utf-8'
            },
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: `...`,
            Charset: 'utf-8'
        }
    },
    Source: 'support@mydomain.com',
    ReturnPath: 'support@mydomain.com',
};
awsConfig.ses.sendEmail(params, (err, data))
```

The received email looks like this in Gmail:
[image: received email]

However, I want to know how to change this name:
[image]

Currently the from name is `support`, because the from email is `support@mydomain.com`. But I want it to be replaced by the company like `GitHub` below.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: More often than not and API would be using a standardized library itself. So it's probably just `'Support Name <support@mydomain.com>'` just like it would be in the RAW mail format.

Comment: should I use the same value for `ReturnPath` ?

Comment: I'm presuming so. It's the standard format for SMTP, so it "should" make sense that is what is basically in use since it's probably just passed through directly into the SMTP messages generated. Not sure if there's a documented source confirming that, but logic would dictate it's a pretty sound thing to test until it proves otherwise.

Comment: Yep. Documented. ALL RFC822 Compliant; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-fields.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:
I set the `Source` attribute in the params to

`'CompanyName <support@mydomain.com>'`

Thanks to @Neil Lunn

Comment: And a big thank you to you for calling this out! I could not spot this in the AWS / SES documentation. Works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this syntax

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create sendEmail params 
var params = {
  Destination: { /* required */
    CcAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more items */
    ],
    ToAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more items */
    ]
  },
  Message: { /* required */
    Body: { /* required */
      Html: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "HTML_FORMAT_BODY"
      },
      Text: {
       Charset: "UTF-8",
       Data: "TEXT_FORMAT_BODY"
      }
     },
     Subject: {
      Charset: 'UTF-8',
      Data: 'Test email'
     }
    },
  Source: 'SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS', /* required */
  ReplyToAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
    /* more items */
  ],
};       

// Create the promise and SES service object
var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendEmail(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
sendPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data.MessageId);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
```